# How to compose functions returning Option with orElse?

Tags: scala, pointfree

Suppose I have two functions `foo: Int => Option[Int]` and `bar: Int => Option[Int]` and use them to process a list:

```
val xs: List[Int] = ...
xs flatMap {x => foo(x) orElse bar(x)}
```

Can I write `xs flatMap (foo orElse bar)` instead of `{x => foo(x) orElse bar(x)}` ?
I can use a 3d party library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the combine operation (`|+|`) of the `Semigroup` typeclass from scalaz.

The default semigroup of `Option` uses the semigroup of the content and combines the values if both values are present. 
So to imitate the `orElse` behaviour, you would need to wrap the `Option`s in the `Tags.FirstVal` tag.

The documentation for `Tags.FirstVal` states:

> Type tag to choose a `scalaz.Semigroup` instance that selects the first operand to append.

You can use `.subst` and `.unsubst` methods of the `Tag`, to wrap and unwrap a type `T` from inside some `F[T]`. It also seems to me that you'd have to help Scala a bit with type inference.

All in all the combined function looks like this:

```
type F[T] = Int => Option[T]
val f = Tags.FirstVal.unsubst(
  Tags.FirstVal.subst[F, Int](foo) |+| 
  Tags.FirstVal.subst[F, Int](bar))
```

And to use it with `flatMap`, you have to use the implicit conversion from to `Option` to `List` in some way. So the `flatMap` call may look like this:

```
xs flatMap (f(_))
```

---

You can also make the `|+|` work as `orElse` if you override the implicit `Monoid` instance for `Option`:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
implicit val inst: Monoid[Option[Int]] = 
  Tags.First.unsubst(scalaz.std.option.optionFirst[Int])

val foo: Int => Option[Int] = x => if (x % 2 == 0) Some(x) else None
val bar: Int => Option[Int] = x => if (x % 3 == 0) Some(x) else None
val xs = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)

xs.flatMap((foo |+| bar)(_))
```

Comment: It seems like this answer is a bit off, as you wanted something more idiomatic, but I'll leave it here as I believe it's the way it has to be done using basic scalaz/cats.

Comment: The answer is fine )) This is what I am looking for.

Comment: @Michael I've updated with a way to make `|+|` work as `orElse`

Comment: Great ! Thank you.  `|+|` looks nice.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know something like this is not available in the standard library, but you can add it yourself using an [implicit class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html):

```
implicit class WithOrElse[T, R](f: T => Option[R]) {
  def orElse(g: T => Option[R])(x: T) = f(x) orElse g(x)
}
```

Example:

```
val foo: Int => Option[Int] = x => if (x % 2 == 0) Some(x) else None
val bar: Int => Option[Int] = x => if (x % 3 == 0) Some(x) else None

val xs = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)

xs flatMap (foo orElse bar)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it available in `cats`  or any other 3d party library ?

Comment: Foo. Beat me to it by about a minute. And with *exactly* the same defintions for `foo` and `bar`. Spooky! Have a +1 :)